# Find out content has fully loaded after adding said content through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm implementing (through pure JavaScript) something like facebook's message loading. Meaning that if you scroll to the end of the page, new (HTML) content is loaded and added to the end of the page. I get this extra content through Ajax. But when I add this (HTML) to the page, it could mean the page has to load extra images. Is there a way I can figure out when the page has finished loading everything, so including all the new images?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just plain JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `load` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) to the appended elements:

```
function LOADER_FUNCTION(e) {
   console.log("LOADED", e.target);
}

var element = document.querySelector('#parent');
for(i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; i++) {
   element.childNodes[i].addEventListener('load', LOADER_FUNCTION);
}
```

This will call the `LOADER_FUNCTION` function when the content within that element is ready. Oddly this doesn't seem to work when attached to the parent.

Edit:

Here is a working example. Although this example is not using Ajax (mainly due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues) it should work under the same conditions. I've used `innerHTML` to set my DOM in order to demonstrate that this event is not limited to `createElement` -> `appendChild`:

```js
(function(){
  // This Code Runs after DOMContentLoaded
  var element = document.getElementById('parent');

  function LOADER_FUNCTION(e) {
     document.querySelector('.status').innerText = ("LOADED " + e.target.tagName);
     console.log("LOADED", e.target);
  }
  
  element.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/OfSN9oH.jpg'>";

  for(i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; i++){
    // Attach new event handler
    element.childNodes[i].addEventListener('load', LOADER_FUNCTION);
  }
})()
```

```html
<div class='status'></div>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Edit 2:

For nested children in append/innerHTML use element.querySelectorAll('*');

https://jsfiddle.net/bckpL9k6/1/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at my end... This is what I did: (trying to insert code here but I dont seem to understand how to add a comment with code...)

Comment: Did you attach the event to every appended element? Meaning every child of the child. This could be a pretty expensive operation but does the job. e.g. <div><div><img src='x'></div></div> <- one for loop is not enough for this.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that does just that by selecting '*' (all children and nested children) in the element - https://jsfiddle.net/bckpL9k6/1/

Comment: @Zippy1970 you can add your code in JSFiddle and post it in the comments. (it doesn't have to function)

Comment: Yes, I attached it to every element. But the LOADER_FUNCTION is never called.

Comment: Does the snippet above show LOADED IMG at the top? I am almost certain this method is working as I tested it with network throttling on Chrome and Edge. However an alternative is element.onload = function(){} but this is only needed for ie9 and below.

Comment: To make it easier you can share a working code (without 'load' events) on jsfiddle with me and I'll try to fix that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94558/discussion-between-schahriar-saffarshargh-and-zippy1970).